# NSMutableParagraphStyle not working properly

Tags: ios, uitextfield

i have problem with NSMutableParagraphStyle

```
 NSMutableParagraphStyle *pageStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
 [pageStyle setLineSpacing:14];
 [pageStyle setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentJustified];
 [pageStyle setFirstLineHeadIndent:5];

 [pageString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:pageStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, self.pageText.length)];

 [pageString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20] range:NSMakeRange(0, self.pageText.length)];
 [pageString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blueColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, self.pageText.length)];

 self.myTextView.attributedText = pageString;
```

**all these are working properly, Except this**

```
 [pageStyle setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentJustified];
 [pageStyle setFirstLineHeadIndent:5];
```

**what can i do fix that?**

Comment: @llario - just (lldb) and crash: i am using arabic string, in english its woking properly